# How many time the digit 6 appear when we count from 6(base 8) to 400 (base 8)?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How many time the digit 6 appear when we count from 6(base 8) to 400 (base 8)?

I am not sure if I am going in the right path. I want to find the most accurate approach of solving this problem.

6(base 8)=6(base 10). Also, 400(base 8)= 256 (base 10). Now, zero will come in base 8 system if we encounter 10 somehow. So, 8(base 10) will yield 10(base 8). Now, in the units place next 6 will come at 16 (base 8) which is eight places away from 6. So, 6 will come in the units place in gaps of 8. So, total number of 6's in units place = int(((256-6)+1)/8)+1=32. Similarly, for tens place 6 will come 8 times per 64(base 10) numbers. Therefore, total 6's in tens place=256/64*8=32. We ignore the effect of first 5 numbers and take the whole as 256 because it does not matter if I take the first 5 into account or not. It does not contain any 6. Now total number of 6s=32+32=64. Is this answer ok? I don't know the correct answer. Please help on the approach.

Comment: Do you count e.g. $66$ as two sixes or just one?

Comment: @ user2345215 As two sixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Your idea of starting from $1$ instead of $6$ makes it easy: One-eighth of the third-place (units) digits are $6$, and one-eighth of the second-place (eights) digits are $6$. So the answer is $\dfrac{400_8}{8} + \dfrac{400_8}{8} = 64_{10}$.

Comment: What do you mean by 1/8 th. Are you counting in the sameway as I am?

Comment: Is there any other way of answering the question? My approach I think is tedious.

Comment: ok i understood 1/8 th. It's same as myself.

Comment: @archangel89 Well, this is another way of approaching the question! This answer is very nice since it avoids enumeration, the idea is to look at the numbers $000, 001, \ldots, 377$ instead. Now you can easily count the occurrences of $6$ as the number of ways to fill $xx6$ and $x6x$ with some other digits, which is clear. (at least I hope this was the idea)

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to do everything in base $8$ until the very end. We'll process each digit separatedly.

$6$ appears as the last digit in $6,16,26,\ldots, 376$, so there are $40$ of them.
$6$ appears as the second last digit in $60,61,\ldots,67;160,161,\ldots,167;\ldots; 360,361,\ldots,367$, so there are $10\cdot4=40$ occurrences.

Everything is accounted for, so there are $40+40=100$ occurrences in total in base $8$, which is $64$ occurrences in base $10$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But, I think you are doing multiplication and division in base 8. Does not it requires help from base 10? I mean we don't know the multiplication table of base 8 system by heart. So, what if I increase the range of numbers?

Comment: I agree with user2345215 that it makes sense to do everything in base $8$. It might not be as easy for you, but after all, the point of the exercise is to familiarise yourself with non-decimal bases.

Comment: @archangel89 It's not as hard as it looks, multiplication by $10$ is just adding a zero to the end in every base and there's no division, $40$ is the length of $0,1,2\ldots,37$. You just have to keep in mind that $7$ is the last digit, so $7+1=10$, $37+1=40$. The solution would be almost the same if you increased the range, $376$ is the largest number containing $6$ in the last digit because $376+2=377+1=400$; similarly for the second last digit, it's not hard to find these numbers if you think about it.